Invert all images in a TImageCollection
I've placed several black images with transparency into a TImageCollection and access these through TVirtualImageLists.  This all works great until I want to use a dark theme where dark images are not very clear (black on black is great for accessibility).
I want to be able to invert all the images in the image collection (preserving transparency) so that I can get white icons for use on a dark background.
I was hoping to do this programmatically rather than supplying two ImageCollections (one black, one white).  But then, what if I wanted a red set of icons...
This project is using Delphi 11.3.
So, how do I invert the images in a TImageCollection?

Are we talking here about VCL or FMX application?

@SilverWarior, TImageCollection comes in Vcl.ImageCollection.pas.

Can you show an example of one of your images?

TImageCollection.Images.Items[index].SourceImages.Items[index].Image is an individual TWICImage.  Iterate the Images and SourceImages collections and manipulate each Image however you want (ie probably by assigning it to a TBitmap, change the pixels, and then assign it back). But, what's wrong with just using a separate TImageCollection for each color theme?

Thanks, @RemyLebeau. I was already heading down this track, and your suggestion works perfectly. Altering the images turned out to be more involved than I initially thought, but I learned a lot about alpha transparency in the process.

First, we must assign the images in the TImageCollection to a TBitmap.  This is fairly easy, as I only have one version of each image.
uses
  System.UITypes,
  System.UIConsts;

procedure TdmImages.ConvertAllToColor(const color: TColor);
var
 i: integer;
 bmp: TBitMap;
begin
  for i := 0 to ImageCollection.Count -1 do
  begin
    var image := ImageCollection.Images[i].SourceImages[0].Image;
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.Assign(image);
    GiveColorToBitmap(bmp, color);
    image.Assign(bmp);
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;

So, above, I'm just iterating over every image, converting it to a bitmap, performing an operation, and assigning it back.  The GiveColorToBitmap is where much of the magic happens.
function GetAValue(Color: TAlphaColor): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte(Color shr 24);
end;

procedure TdmImages.GiveColorToBitmap(const bmp: TBitmap; const color: TColor);
type
  PAlphaColorArray = ^TAlphaColorArray;
  TAlphaColorArray = array[Word] of TAlphaColor;
var
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  line: PAlphaColorArray;
  Pixel: TAlphaColor;
  R, G, B, A: Byte;
begin
  R := GetRValue(color);
  G := GetGValue(color);
  B := GetBValue(color);
  for y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
  begin
    line := bmp.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
    begin
      pixel := line[x];
      A := GetAValue(pixel);
      if (A <> 0) then { if not completely transparent }
      begin
        pixel := B + (G shl 8) + (R shl 16) + (A shl 24); { Recompose TAlphaColor from parts}
        line[x] := PremultiplyAlpha(pixel);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

What stumped me for quite a while was that I had to use PremultiplyAlpha to recalculate the correct pixel colour.  Alpha transparency is much more complicated than I had realised.  There are probably more optimisations I can make (suggestions welcome), but this code works great.

In order to understand more about why you should use PremultiplyAlpha I suggest you read Alpha compositing->Straight versus premultiplied.

From what I understand this is needed because the three different base colours (Red, Green and Blue) have different emission values so you need to correct for this. Unfortunately I can't find the article that I read in the past about this topic at the moment. I do know I was searching about AlphaBlending of two pictures together and how it works when I did found that article. So this might help you find the same or similar article that would explain this in more detail.

Also after watching your Re-Colouring Bitmaps with Correct Alpha Transparency - Delphi 240 video I was wondering since you are going with Mono-Chrome theme if it might not be easier of just loading your images as Bitmap Mask. Then all you would have to change are Background and Foreground colours since Bitmap Mask will define where foreground colour is rendered and where not. Granted on VCL application would probably lose that smooth edge that is done by performing Anti-Aliassing on an image.

And if you really want to modernise your application use Skia and replace all your raster images with vector-graphic images like SVG's.

The only reason the altered bitmaps needs to be premultiplied is that the source bitmaps, in this case, are premultiplied; It is not a general requirement of "changing the color of a bitmap" or "working with alpha transparency".

R, G, and B in the code are constant. Only A changes. This means that you can replace the whole calculation inside the loop with a lookup into an array of 256 RGBA colors. Populate the lookup outside the loop. Never mind about the A=0 case; It's faster to just do the lookup. With this the whole inner loop block becomes a one-liner: line[x] := Lookup[line[x] shr 24];
